# How to do super resolution image with onnx and opencv using c++ ?, its working fine using python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, deep-learning, onnx

I have [`animesr.onnx`](https://github.com/rizkyeky/HighResApp-Flutter/tree/main/assets) for my super resolution ios/macos app so I need to convert my python codes to c++ codes. These is my python codes:

```
session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession('animesr.onnx')

img = cv2.imread('imgs/naruto.jpg')
ori_h, ori_w, _ = img.shape
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img = cv2.resize(img, (512,512))
img = (np.array(img) / 255.0).astype(np.float32)
img = np.transpose(img, (2, 0, 1))
img = np.expand_dims(img, 0)

input_name = session.get_inputs()[0].name
output_name = session.get_outputs()[0].name

input_feed = {input_name: img}
output = session.run([output_name], input_feed)

output = output[0].clip(0, 1) * 255
output = output.astype(np.uint8)
output = np.squeeze(output)
output = np.transpose(output, (1, 2, 0))
output = cv2.cvtColor(output, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
output = cv2.resize(output, (ori_w*4, ori_h*4))
cv2.imwrite('naruto_animesr.jpg', output)
```

Its working fine and the result is like this (left is before, right is after)
[image: naruto_sr]

And this is my c++ codes:

```
Ort::Session session(env, ORT_TSTR(modelPath), sessionOptions);

cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread(imagePath, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
// cv::Mat blob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(inputImage, 1.0/255, cv::Size(512,512), cv::Scalar(), true);
cv::Mat resizedImage;
cv::resize(inputImage, resizedImage, cv::Size(512,512));
cv::Mat floatImage;
resizedImage.convertTo(floatImage, CV_32FC3, 1.0/255.0);

Ort::MemoryInfo memoryInfo = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu(OrtArenaAllocator, OrtMemTypeDefault);
std::vector<int64_t> inputShape = {1, 3, 512, 512};
  
Ort::Value inputTensor = Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(memoryInfo, (float*) floatImage.data, 3*512*512, inputShape.data(), inputShape.size());

std::vector<const char*> inputNames = {"input"};
std::vector<const char*> outputNames = {"output"};

std::vector<Ort::Value> outputTensor = session.Run(Ort::RunOptions{}, inputNames.data(), &inputTensor, 1, outputNames.data(), outputNames.size());

Ort::TensorTypeAndShapeInfo outputInfo = outputTensor[0].GetTensorTypeAndShapeInfo();
int channels = outputInfo.GetShape()[1]; // 3
int height = outputInfo.GetShape()[2]; // 2048
int width = outputInfo.GetShape()[3]; // 2048
  
const float* outputData = outputTensor[0].GetTensorMutableData<float>();
  
cv::Mat outputImage(height, width, CV_32FC(channels), const_cast<float*>(outputData));
cv::Mat uint8Image;
outputImage.convertTo(uint8Image, CV_8UC3, 255);
cv::Mat bgrOutput;
cv::cvtColor(uint8Image, bgrOutput, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
cv::imwrite(outputPath, bgrOutput);
```

This is the result
[image: naruto_fail1]
and this is the result with cv::ddn::blobFromImage()
[image: naruto_fail2]

Both are suck results, different with my python result.

I thing the problem is from pre-processing image as input before run the model and processing the output to become cv image, I am bad at matrix operation like transform, transpose, reshape, etc.

Can you guys help me provide the correct processing image codes with opencv c++

Thank you

Comment: looks like dimension order is messed up. learn what NCHW and NHWC mean. then figure out what you're doing that affects dimension order and what you _didn't_ do to get it back into expected order.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you right, unlike opencv python that use numpy to do matrix operation is easy to reorder matrix, opencv c++ has own matrix, so if i print size() of cv::mat only 2d (height and width) are showed and i can't do cv::transposeND to reorder dim because only 2d are provided. it use cv::Vec3b to put their channels (rgb/bgr) values so just like (2d array of vec3). meanwhile, onnx::session.run need 1d array as input so i have to reshape cv::mat and the onnx output is also 1d array of float that i don't understand how to convert it to become cv::mat

Comment: the `dnn` module has "blob" functions that can transpose/permute dimension order.